# Search API with multiple conditions

Tags: content-search

Sitecore 9.3

What I have till now:

I am able to filter items based on a template using the search context.

```
var unversionedImageTemplateId = ID.Parse(Constants.UnversionedImageTemplateId);
var jpegTemplateId = ID.Parse(Constants.Jpeg);

var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
  .Where(x => x.TemplateId == unversionedImageTemplateId || x.TemplateId == jpegTemplateId)
```

What I am trying to do:

I want to put one more condition based upon the value of a field, a check box.

What I tried:

1. I tried using `.Where` after the code I have.
2. I tried applying the condition using `&&` in the same `Where` command.

But I always get the following error.

```
Exception: System.NotSupportedException
Message: The method 'get_Item' is not supported.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq
```

Any idea how to move ahead with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Predicate builder to build your query. You will have something like:

```
      var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
      predicate = predicate.And<SearchResultItem>(i => i.TemplateId == [Template ID]);
     #Get items under specific node or Items from specific location in Sitecore –
     predicate = predicate.And<SearchResultItem>(i => i.Paths.Contains([Location Item ID]));
     #Get items for context language only  –
     predicate = predicate.And<SearchResultItem>(item => item.Language == Context.Language.Name);
     # get items which have a field value
     predicate = predicate.And<SearchResultItem>(item => item["fieldname"] == "Sitecore")
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the predicates.